# UICollectionView in Keyboard extension does not work after connecting to delegate/datasource

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard, uicollectionviewdelegate

I have made a custom keyboard extension using storyboard, and it works fine in the Simulator.

[image: keyboard A-Z View]

I need to add emoji function to it.

I have done this by adding a 2nd view on the storyboard and set it to hidden in viewDidLoad and you press a button on the main (A-z) view reveal the 2nd View (emojis).

[image: outline]

In the 2nd View I use a collectionView to layout the emoji.  It all runs ok in the Simulator.  I can see the collection view in grey.

[image: collectionView in 2nd View]

But when I connect the collectionView to the collectionView datasource and delegate in the keyboardviewcontroller like this:

[image: connecting to datasource and delegate]

And then run it in the simulator, I get an error to say the plugin in is invalidated and the keyboard will not load in the simulator.

What am I doing wrong, please?

Thank you for any advise.